# how to install nvm? I have installed nvm and my cmd prompt cannot recognize the nvm and this is what I get

Tags: node.js, express, nvm

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\DELL 5558>nvm --version
'nvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\DELL 5558>

Comment: How did you install it? Make sure to start an elevated command prompt (CMD as administrator) and use the global flag: `npm install -g nvm`

Comment: Can you find it in your PATH (was it added automatically during install)?